# How to upgrade from version 2.31 to version 5.3.1 of pac4j-http and fix the arguments to org.pac4j.core.credentials.authenticator.Authenticator?

Tags: java, spring-security, pac4j

I am trying to upgrade pac4j-http:2.31 to 5.3.1 and need help dealing with a breaking change in the argument list of the `validate()` function in the [`Authenticator`](https://www.pac4j.org/docs/authenticators.html) interface.

Earlier I was using `Authenticator(org.pac4j.core.credentials.authenticator.Authenticator)` which had method `public void validate(TokenCredentials credentials, WebContext context)` and now it changed to `public void validate(Credentials credentials, WebContext context, SessionStore sessionStore)`

Earlier code below:

```
private static class TestAuthenticator implements Authenticator<TokenCredentials>
  {
    @Override
    public void validate(TokenCredentials credentials, WebContext context)
    {
      if (TEST_TOKEN.equals(credentials.getToken()))
      {
        credentials.setUserProfile(mockUserProfile());
      }
    }
  }
```

So my question is, how to upgrade to this latest version of 5.3.1. where the validate method of `Authenticator` class has `Credential` argument instead of `TokenCredential`?  How can we validate token now since the validate method arguments changed?

Comment: As a matter of cleaning up the question, can you clarify what this has to do with Spring Security? If nothing, then please remove those labels for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Credentials` is a super-class of `TokenCredentials`, it seems like you'd be able to do:

```java
private static class TestAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
  @Override
  public void validate(Credentials credentials, WebContext context, SessionStore sessionStore) {
    TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = (TokenCredentials) credentials;
    if (TEST_TOKEN.equals(tokenCredentials.getToken())) {
      tokenCredentials.setUserProfile(mockUserProfile());
    }
  }
}
```

Apologies, though, if I'm missing something. It seems like the generic type was removed from `Authenticator`, meaning that a cast is now required.